# flutter_sms or sms_advance is not working

Tags: kotlin, gradle, sms, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I tried build an app to send sms using flutter. I used examples of flutter_sms and sms_advance. Noth are not work. An error occured as

```
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_sms' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
```

According to the some helps, I checked and results are,
1 build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the result was whe check gradle version on command line.

```
C:\Users\Hemantha>gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-08-17 07:06:47 UTC
Revision:     8afbf24b469158b714b36e84c6f4d4976c86fcd5

Kotlin:       1.9.0
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          1.8.0_281 (Oracle Corporation 25.281-b09)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

android version is Girrafe, and pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^2.1.1
  flutter_sms: ^2.3.3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
....
```

direct caller example also is working. but not succeed sms. Please can anyone help me to solve this.